# How to get ICacheEntry from Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache

Tags: .net, caching

In my application I use `MemoryCache` and I wanted to add a functionality to it. When I read a value from the cache I want to check against its expiration date and if it's soon, I want to run a refresh (which takes long) for this key in the background.

To achieve this I need to get `ICacheEntry` which has the info about the expiration date, but there is no way to access it through `IMemoryCache` interface which I use. So I decided to derive from it and add a method to get `ICacheEntry`. The problem is that `EntriesCollection` in `MemoryCache` is private instead of protected.

Is there any other way to get cache entry (not just value of cached entry) using this library? Or should I use some other library to achieve what I need?

Answer (score 1):

```
var cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition = typeof(MemoryCache).GetProperty("EntriesCollection", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);

// Populate the definition with your IMemoryCache instance.  
// It needs to be cast as a dynamic, otherwise you can't
// loop through it due to it being a collection of objects.
var cacheEntriesCollection = cacheEntriesCollectionDefinition.GetValue(this) as dynamic;

// Define a new list we'll be adding the cache entries too
List<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry> cacheCollectionValues = new List<Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry>();

foreach (var cacheItem in cacheEntriesCollection)
{
    // Get the "Value" from the key/value pair which contains the cache entry   
    Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.ICacheEntry cacheItemValue = cacheItem.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetValue(cacheItem, null);

    // Add the cache entry to the list
    cacheCollectionValues.Add(cacheItemValue);
}

// You can now loop through the cacheCollectionValues list created above however you like.`
```